# how can i get customer details by using access token with magento api

Tags: api, magento, access-token

I am using [Magento REST authentication api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html) in that I am getting the access token and secret key

By using this access token I need to get customer id and customer details.

Firstly, how can I get customer details such as customer id, customer name etc.

Comment: Have you googled `magento api customer details`?

Comment: Yeah. i have googled, but so for no luck. having api to get all customer details,but i needed the login customerID.

Comment: I think you have to use the "customer User type " that only return id of the customer

Comment: "CustomerUserType" please describe it @chanz

Answer (score 2):

For getting customer details use

```
 http://magentohost/api/rest/customers
```

For getting customer for a particular id is

```
http://magentohost/api/rest/customers/:customerId
```

For more information check [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html)

Comment: how do we get customerID by using access token?

Comment: You want to get id of particular customer only...and http://magentohost/api/rest/customers returns id with other details also...

Comment: Chanz, how will I find "CustomerID" of the logged customer using this access token?  This access token belongs to a "logged customer"

Comment: Ok i get you ...http://postimage.org/image/a65drv29x/ here i am using customer type role and return the id ogf the customer with email..is this ok

Comment: Seems to be correct.  May I know the web service method to be called?

Comment: thanks I think it will work for us.

Comment: can you share what was the answer? or how did it work..

Comment: im getting this error "<message>Access denied</message>" see screenshot http://postimage.org/image/bi7ypxt8l/

Comment: are you sure the last two credentials are oauth_token and verifier..As my knowledge it should be oauth_token and oauth_token_secret which are obtained by magentohost/oauth/token...be sure the last steps in Oauth authentication are completed refer ths link http://blog.magikcommerce.com/magento-rest-api-how-to-take-advantage-of-rest-in-magento/